# Usage of nested Route element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React app, I can see the following code;

```
const pages = [
    {
      pageLink: '/state/:stateCode',
      view: State,
      displayName: t('State'),
      animationDelayForNavbar: 0.7,
      showInNavbar: false,
    },
  ];

<Route render={({location}) => (
              <div className="Almighty-Router">
                <Navbar
                  pages={pages}
                  darkMode={darkMode}
                  setDarkMode={setDarkMode}
                />
                <Switch location={location}>
                  {pages.map((page, index) => {
                    return (
                      <Route
                        exact
                        path={page.pageLink}
                        render={({match}) => (
                          <page.view key={match.params.stateCode || index} />
                        )}
                        key={index}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                  <Redirect to="/" />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            )}
          />
```

My question is why is there a nested `<Route>` used below ? 
What purpose does it serve? Can we somehow implement this without nested `<Route>` element ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your component might have been developed sometime back.
The recommended method of rendering something with a `<Route>` is to use children elements. There are, however, a few other methods you can use to render something with a `<Route>`. These are provided mostly for supporting apps that were built with earlier versions of the router before hooks were introduced.
Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to render a nested route, specially because your Parent route is not defining any path.

You can directly render he above component like below

```
          <div className="Almighty-Router">
            <Navbar
              pages={pages}
              darkMode={darkMode}
              setDarkMode={setDarkMode}
            />
            <Switch>
              {pages.map((page, index) => {
                return (
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path={page.pageLink}
                    render={({match}) => (
                      <page.view key={match.params.stateCode || index} />
                    )}
                    key={index}
                  />
                );
              })}
              <Redirect to="/" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
```

Also the `Switch` component doesn't need a `location` prop